# replace row values based on another row value in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation

I have a trivial question, though I am struggling to find a simple answer. I have a data table that looks something like this:

```
dt <- data.table(id= c(A,A,A,A,B,B,B,C,C,C), time=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3), score = c(10,15,13,25,NA,NA,18,29,19))
dt
#     id  time  score
# 1:   A    1    NA
# 2:   A    2    10
# 3:   A    3    15
# 4:   A    4    13
# 5:   B    1    NA
# 6:   B    2    25
# 7:   B    3    NA
# 8:   B    4    NA
# 9:   C    1    18
# 10:  C    2    29
# 11:  C    3    NA
# 12:  C    4    19
```

I would like to replace the missing values of my group "B" with the values of "A".

The final dataset should look something like this

```
final
#     id  time  score
# 1:   A    1    NA
# 2:   A    2    10
# 3:   A    3    15
# 4:   A    4    13
# 5:   B    1    NA
# 6:   B    2    25
# 7:   B    3    15
# 8:   B    4    13
# 9:   C    1    18
# 10:  C    2    29
# 11:  C    3    NA
# 12:  C    4    19
```

In other words, conditional on the fact that B is NA, I would like to replace the score of "A". Do note that "C" remains NA. 
I am struggling to find a clean way to do this using data.table. However, if it is simpler with other methods it would still be ok.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Your reproducible data is a mess (not reproducible). Please fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option where we get the index of the rows which are `NA` for 'score' and the 'id' is "B", use that to replace the NA with the corresponding 'score' value from 'A'

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(dt)[id == 'B', which(is.na(score))]
dt[, score:= replace(score, id == 'B' & is.na(score), score[which(id == 'A')[i1]])]
```

---

Or a similar option in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
   mutate(score = replace(score, id == "B" & is.na(score), 
         score[which(id == "A")[i1]))
```

Comment: Great thanks Akrun, is there also a solution with dplyr that you could suggest?

Comment: @Alex you can use the same method with `dplyr` as well, updated