# How to replace an entire row between two rows based on a column

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I am dealing a with a very large mRNA splicing dataset. Here is a toy dataset to exemplify the problem:

```
test_df <- data.frame(
  start = c(2, 9, 13, 19, 13, 20, 25, 35, 39),
  end = c(8, 12, 18, 24, 16, 24, 30, 38, 45),
  gene_id = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
  exon_identity = c(NA, "Upstream", NA, "Downstream", "Event", NA, "Upstream", "Downstream", NA)
)

> test_df
  start end gene_id exon_identity
1     2   8       A          <NA>
2     9  12       A      Upstream
3    13  18       A          <NA>
4    19  24       A    Downstream
5    13  16       A         Event
6    20  24       B          <NA>
7    25  30       B      Upstream
8    35  38       B    Downstream
9    39  45       B          <NA>
```

For every unique value in `gene_id` column, I would like to replace an entire row if it is present between "Upstream" and "Downstream" values in the `exon_identity` column i.e. replace row 3 with row 5. What makes it difficult for me is that there are certain genes in the `gene_id` column which do not have a row that needs to be replaced, e.g. "B" in the `gene_id` column.

This question goes in the direction of previously asked questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75442535/in-r-how-to-replace-values-in-specific-rows-with-those-from-another-row-based) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60761465/replace-row-values-based-on-another-row-value-in-a-data-table).

Based on those and other resources, I have tried:

```
library(tidyverse)

test_replace <- test_df %>% 
  group_by(gene_id) %>% 
  mutate(start = replace(start, row_number() > which(exon_idnetity == "Upstream") & row_number() < which(exon_idnetity == "Downstream"), start[exon_idnetity == "Event"]),
         end = replace(end, row_number() > which(exon_idnetity == "Upstream") & row_number() < which(exon_idnetity == "Downstream"), end[exon_idnetity == "Event"]),
         exon_idnetity = replace(exon_idnetity, row_number() > which(exon_idnetity == "Upstream") & row_number() < which(exon_idnetity == "Downstream"), "Event")
         )


Warning message:
There were 2 warnings in `mutate()`.
The first warning was:
ℹ In argument: `start = replace(...)`.
ℹ In group 1: `gene_id = "A"`.
Caused by warning in `x[list] <- values`:
! number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
ℹ Run dplyr::last_dplyr_warnings() to see the 1 remaining warning. 
> 
> test_replace
# A tibble: 9 × 4
# Groups:   gene_id [2]
  start   end gene_id exon_idnetity
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <chr>        
1     2     8 A       NA           
2     9    12 A       Upstream     
3    NA    NA A       Event        
4    19    24 A       Downstream   
5    13    16 A       Event        
6    20    24 B       NA           
7    25    30 B       Upstream     
8    35    38 B       Downstream   
9    39    45 B       NA
```

Desired output:

```
> desired_outcome 
  start end gene_id exon_idnetity
1     2   8       A          <NA>
2     9  12       A      Upstream
3    13  16       A         Event
4    19  24       A    Downstream
5    20  24       B          <NA>
6    25  30       B      Upstream
7    35  38       B    Downstream
8    39  45       B          <NA>
```

A solution, preferably using tidyverse package would be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Will there ever be more than one row between`"Upstream"` and `"Downstream"`? What about more than one “replacement” row after `"Downstream"`?

Comment: In cases where the row needs to be replaced there is always only one row in-between "Upstream" and "Downstream". The "Event" row can be multiple rows below the downstream and not necessarily right below it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the toy example, reordering your data set gives you almost all of what you want.  Will that work in the real data set?  E.g.

```
library(tidyverse)
test_df |>
  mutate(
    sandwich = lag(exon_identity == 'Upstream') & lead(exon_identity == 'Downstream')
  ) |>
  replace_na(list(sandwich = FALSE)) |>
  group_by(gene_id) |>
  arrange(start) |>
  ungroup() |>
  filter(!sandwich) |>
  select(-sandwich)
```

(In the toy example, `group_by` and `ungroup` are *not* needed.  I added them in case it was needed/useful in the real data set.)

Comment: Nice insight. You could simplify the pipeline (albeit with a more complex `filter()` condition) as: `test_df |> filter(!replace_na(lag(exon_identity == 'Upstream') & lead(exon_identity == 'Downstream'), FALSE)) |>  arrange(gene_id, start)`.

Comment: Thank you! This is a very elegant solution and does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

If @MelissaKey is right about the structure of your actual data, their solution will work nicely. Otherwise, here’s a function that does the job along with `group_modify()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

replace_rows <- function(x, ...) {
  is_bad <- replace_na(
    lag(x$exon_identity) == "Upstream" & lead(x$exon_identity) == "Downstream",
    FALSE
  )
  if (any(is_bad)) {
    is_event <- replace_na(x$exon_identity == "Event", FALSE)
    x <- x %>%
      filter(!is_bad, !is_event) %>%
      add_row(
        filter(x, is_event),
        .before = which(is_bad)
      )
  }
  x
}

test_df %>% 
  group_by(gene_id) %>% 
  group_modify(replace_rows) %>%
  ungroup()
```

```
# A tibble: 8 × 4
  gene_id start   end exon_identity
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>        
1 A           2     8 <NA>         
2 A           9    12 Upstream     
3 A          13    16 Event        
4 A          19    24 Downstream   
5 B          20    24 <NA>         
6 B          25    30 Upstream     
7 B          35    38 Downstream   
8 B          39    45 <NA>
```